# Xamarin.Forms: How to implement lock screen audio player controls

Tags: xamarin.forms, controls, lockscreen, audio-player

I'm building a Xamarin.Forms app that's essentially an audio player, and I need to implement lock screen controls (user can play/pause/ff/rw audio player without unlocking phone) for the audio player on both platforms. I've never done this before, and I'm having some difficulty finding solid documentation that explains how it's done.

Is it possible to do this in Xamarin.Forms, or will I have to implement the functionality separately in both iOS and Android native projects? In either case, how? I'm junior and need a little bit of a jump start.

Thanks for your time, much appreciated. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the MediaManager plugin for Xamarin Forms?

https://blog.xamarin.com/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/

https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager

Comment: I haven't, but I'm looking into it now. Thanks for the lead! I'll let you know if it works out.

Comment: Ok, I implemented this plugin in the project and it's working great! Thanks so much for the recommendation, you saved me a lot of coding.

Comment: How did you implement screen lock controls?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found something or not. I struggled a lot with this.
This plugin here https://github.com/DanielCKennedy/XamMusic
does what you need. You can modify the implementation to play music from your files then the system music files.

But it still has no option to play video on locked screen. I have worked on that and making a sample to help others. Its ready for ios but not for android at this stage.